# java.net.BindException: Address already in use in tomcat

Tags: java, web-deployment, war, tomcat8

I am receiving error while trying to deploy web application in tomcat8.5

The war file is placed in CATALINA_BASE: ea-tomcat85/webapps/ROOT.war

I have try some steps to solve the error without success.

**Step 1:** I kill the process running on `port 8080`

```
       #netstat -pant | grep "8080"
        tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      511871/java

       #kill 511871
```

restarted tomcat but receiving the same error,Also

**Step 2:** change my application's port number in my `application.properties` to something like `server.port=5815`.
Still the same error.

Below is the configuration of server

**Services** in `server.xml` in `CATALINA_BASE`

```
        <Service name="Catalina">


<Connector port="10000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" xpoweredBy="false"/>

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />


   
  
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
   
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false" deployXML="false">
   
   
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" showReport="false" showServerInfo="false"/>
  </Host>
</Engine>
<Connector port="10001" protocol="AJP/1.3" xpoweredBy="false" secretRequired="false"/>
</Service>
```

**Services** in `server.xml` in `CATALINA_HOME`

```
       <Service name="Catalina">

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
   
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
</Engine>
 </Service>
```

`setenv.sh` in `CATALINA_BASE`

```
     [root@xxx bin]# cat setenv.sh
     # Your customizations can go here, for example, CATALINA_OPTS
     # example from https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source
     # Trade some security for startup speed by using non-blocking entropy:
     # CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"

     JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
     CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/bin/catalina.pid"

     # DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE OR ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
     . /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/user-setenv.sh
     [root@xxx bin]#
```

`setenv.sh` in `CATALINA_HOME`

```
     [root@xxx bin]# cat setenv.sh
     export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx6248m"
     export CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/bin/catalina.pid"
     export CATALINA_BASE="/home/wematanzania/ea-tomcat85"
     JRE_HOME= "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre"
     [root@xxx bin]#
```

**Error description** in `catalina.out` file in `CATALINA_BASE: /logs/catalina.out`

```
21-May-2021 06:05:10.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.828 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-10000"]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.841 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-10000]]
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1076)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:846)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
            Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
                    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
                    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
                    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
                    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:222)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1143)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
                    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:599)
                    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
                    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1074)
                    ... 13 more
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.844 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.846 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.861 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-10001"]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.862 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-10001]]
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1076)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:846)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
            Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
                    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
                    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
                    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
                    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:222)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1143)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
                    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:599)
                    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1074)
                    ... 13 more
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 981 ms
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.898 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.898 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.66]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.910 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    21-May-2021 06:05:10.924 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 61 ms
```

**Update**: port 10000 and 10001

```
 [root@xxx logs]# netstat -pant | grep "10000" 
    tcp6 0 0 :::10000 :::* LISTEN 503271/java 
    [root@xxx logs]# netstat -pant | grep "10001" 
    tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:10001 :::* LISTEN 503271/java 
    [root@xxx logs]#
```

Also while starting tomcat I receive the below output.

```
[root@xxx bin]# ./startup.sh
/opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/setenv.sh: line 4: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre: Is a directory
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/profile/ea-tomcat85
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/profile/ea-tomcat85/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:    -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx6248m
Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85/bin/catalina.pid
Tomcat started.
```

Iam not so sure if  `JRE_HOME:  /` has to be like that . But the path are set in both `setenv.sh` files

**Update:** After commenting out connector on port 10000 and 10001, And changed the port of tomcat in `application.properties` back to `server.port=8080`

I receive the below error from the browser
[image: Browser Error]

Catalina.out in CATALINA_BASE: logs/catalina.out

```
21-May-2021 11:18:09.524 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.66
21-May-2021 11:18:09.526 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 8 2021 22:44:01 UTC
21-May-2021 11:18:09.526 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.66.0
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_292-b10
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Red Hat, Inc.
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/profile/ea-tomcat85
21-May-2021 11:18:09.527 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/profile/ea-tomcat85/conf/logging.properties
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx6248m
21-May-2021 11:18:09.528 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
21-May-2021 11:18:09.529 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/profile/ea-tomcat85
21-May-2021 11:18:09.529 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/cpanel/ea-tomcat85
21-May-2021 11:18:09.529 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/profile/ea-tomcat85/temp
21-May-2021 11:18:09.529 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
21-May-2021 11:18:09.617 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-May-2021 11:18:09.631 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
21-May-2021 11:18:09.654 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 664 ms
21-May-2021 11:18:09.690 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
21-May-2021 11:18:09.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.66]
21-May-2021 11:18:09.711 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-May-2021 11:18:09.722 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 68 ms
```

And the **ROOT.war** does not get unpacked inside `CATALINA_BASE :  /home/profile/ea-tomcat85/webapps/ROOT.war`

This is my first time deploying a war file in live tomcat server, I have read a lot of post regarding this,but still I dont know what exactly am I doing wrong.Kindly assist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you still have any ports in TIME_WAIT state after kllling the Tomcat? NB You should not kill it, you should shut it down properly with the command supplied.

Comment: Apparently port is still busy. Have you checked that server is actually killed and releases the port? Does it disappear from netstat? You can kill -9 if needed. Have your tried calling telnet command to check if client can connect to this port?

Comment: @Piotr Yes if kill the port it disappear  from netstat.

Comment: Could you please remove all the commented parts from the XML? It's very hard to read like this.

Comment: Does the exception you posted appear like this *after* you changed the port to 5815?

Comment: @geanakuch done. Yes after changing the port the exception still appears like that.

Comment: I just realized that the stacktrace is not complaining about port 8080. The exceptions appear on 10000 and 10001. So it's the AJP port that is not released. Maybe run netstat to check those ports?

Comment: @geanakuch I have updated the question to show port 10000 and 10001. Thanks in advance

Comment: @GabrielRogath: even if the connectors on ports 10000 and 10001 fail to start, the connector on port 8080 should work correctly. BTW: if you don't use those connectors delete/comment them out.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz : I heve commented them out. The above arror has gone, but I receive another error in the browser but not in catalina.out.  Let me update the question to see the shown error from the browser.

Comment: The above error could be you're using the wrong address. Which URL are you using? It should be something like ```http://localhost:8080/yourwebapp```.

Comment: @geanakuch: I am deploying it to a live server

Comment: OK, there should be en entry in a log file for sure. If it's not in ```catalina.out```, it should be somewhere else, depending on how your system is set up. If you get a 500, it's a good guess that your application is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **java.net.BindException:** was solved with the scenario provided above together with help from the comments.

But the **`Internal Server Error`** was caused by missing **module** `setEnv` in server configuration of tomcat. Added that module to the server I could access the application without an error.